# How to get the size of each SharePoint site using Microsoft Graph or SharePoint API?

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I tried using graph API for reports https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/reportroot-getsharepointsiteusagestorage?view=graph-rest-1.0 this returns the required output but in CSV.

`GET /reports/getSharePointSiteUsageStorage(period='{period_value}')`

Output fields in the CSV are
`Report Refresh Date,Site Id,Site URL,Owner Display Name,Is Deleted,Last Activity Date,File Count,Active File Count,Page View Count,Visited Page Count,Storage Used (Byte),Storage Allocated (Byte),Root Web Template,Owner Principal Name,Report Period`

I am concerned with only **Site Id, Storage Used (Byte),Storage Allocated (Byte)** fields. Is there a way to get this information as JSON output? or is there a way to get this information using some other API?

Answer (score 1):

You could get site usuage information with this:

```
https://<siteUrl>/_api/site/usage
```

Reference: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/91599/retrieve-site-collection-quota-and-used-storage-from-rest-or-jsom